# Use of ckeditor "key" CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on('key', function (e){

Tags: events, event-handling, ckeditor

I realize there are questions about how to implement an event handler for CKEDITOR 4. I am able to use this code to get the key-down data, but I can't seem to get the data after a key-up:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on('key', function (e){
    document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
});
```

So when I type a string like "aaa" into the text editor field, the first character is never fetched. So my div id="preview" will only show "aa". I've iterated over the e object, which is quite complex, but nothing there strikes me as useful to solving this.

I also don't see other people writing about this. There doesn't seem to be a "keyup" event in CKEDITOR, though I see it written about a lot. "keyup" must have been in older versions?

I hope I have clearly stated my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].on('contentDom', function() {
    CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].document.on('keyup', function(event) {
        document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
    });
});
```

I'll wait a bit before checking as answer, in case others would like to contribute.

Comment: Yes, it works. Note: you use either `CKEDITOR.instances['editor']` or `CKEDITOR.instances.editor`, 3 times. For readability and consistency, I'd suggest preceding this with `var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor']` and using that instead (though it's an extra line of code)

Answer (score 2):

This is a correct way:

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    editor.editable().attachListener( 'keyup', editor.document, function( evt ) {
        // ...
    } );
} );
```

There are some rules regarding listening on DOM events. See:

- [editor#contentDom event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom),
- [editable#attachListener method](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener).

Also, I'd rather avoid calling `editor.getData()` on every keyup. This method is not very lightweight - it does a lot more than simple reading `.innerHTML`. Thus, you should think of  periodic update (when the editor is focused) or the [onchange plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/onchange).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use onChange plugin : http://ckeditor.com/addon/onchange

```
...
on: {
    change: function(event) {
        // your code
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll experiment with it!

Comment: This is an example of how to use that plugin to create a live preview: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/recipe-live-preview-of-ckeditor.html

Answer (score 1):

**its work for me**

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
    e.editor.on('contentDom', function() {
        var editable = e.editor.editable();
        editable.attachListener(editable, 'keyup', function() {
            var content = editable.getData()
            //your content               
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not working because keyup has not been fired. I combined this answer here with the suggestion to use setTimeout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33261102/ckeditor-getdata-returning-stale-data-last-change-missing-in-source-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1). And now it works for me. Additionally I'm using the key event in source code view and change event in WYSIWYG view. I ignore CTL and CMD (1114203, 1114129) to be able to correctly recognize c&p in source code view. 200 ms seems enough time for my case.

```
  CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on('key', function (e) {
    if ([1114203, 1114129].indexOf(e.data.keyCode) === -1) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()
        // do something with data
      }, 200)
    }
  }.bind(this))

  CKEDITOR.instances.editor.on('change', function () {
    let data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()
    // do something with data
  }.bind(this))
```