# ckeditor getData() returning stale data (last change missing) in source mode

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

try typing in **source** mode on http://ckeditor.com/demo to debug use 
`CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].on("key", function(e) {console.log("change: " + e.editor.getData())})` in console

I always see one character less in the console, so If I have typed `abc` I see `ab`

note: using key event because of https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12031Guidelines
and
[How to detect CKEditor source mode on change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358203/how-to-detect-ckeditor-source-mode-on-change-event)

Comment: I checked the code once. I agree the working is different. It is showing one instance older than the current instance. Can I see the implementation of getData()? What I feel is, You are trying to get the data from the editor even before you are allowing the change to be made on the editor.

Comment: I am using ng-ckeditor to make it work with my angular. ng-ckeditor uses getData() internally.

Comment: Good to know that my analysis helped :) Please mark it as the Answer(Tick mark) So that the question would seem resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a detailed answer here with my analysis.

As I said earlier, the getData() is being fetched even before the key stroke is being recorded as a part of the text in the Editor. That is why you see the previous data(The data that's before the key press)

I am not able to help you much with the current situation as very minimal code is exposed. I am not really sure how you are using it, and what lines are presiding it.

But, I will post in my analysis-
I created a waitfunc() which just sets-timeout for 5secs. I did this to observe if the key is recorded in the editor first or the data is being taken first.

```
function waitfunc() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("wait")
    }, 5000)
}

CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].on("key", function(e) {
    waitfunc();
    console.log("change: " + e.editor.getData());
    waitfunc();
})
```

I see the data is being taken first. And then new key pressed is added as a part of editor. I have added 'c' at the end of the paragraph.

[image: Both timeouts happen after the data is grabbed]

So, please have a look at the code once(the ordering of lines of code or whatever). And if possible, share more code, I can help more than this.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is that the `"key"` event is similar to `onkeydown` in javascript, so looking at the editor's contents on key down means looking at it before the character has been added. You should be looking at the `"keyup"` event, which is fired after the contents have been altered. Much like the `setTimeout` solution, but a little more "proper".

See here for a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713575/use-of-ckeditor-key-ckeditor-instances-editor-onkey-function-e) and code example